# Are the questions about non-profit organization "on topic"?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions, topicality

The current [proposal Charity Work](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92079/charity-work) (volunteering) could have a lot of questions common with this page.

Would the question mentioned here be off-topic on this page?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all practical questions related to that topic are off-topic here, just like most practical questions from personal finance are off-topic here too.

I skimmed the sample questions too, nothing that'd be on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Foobar that these questions are off topic because they are about practical information and not economic phenomena. I would like to emphasize that economists (or most of us) don't have problems with non-profit organizations. Theoretical questions about them, such as how to measure the efficiency of NGOs or under what kind of assumptions can altruism result in Pareto-efficient outcomes are welcome.